# How to create a function that returns N number of arrays from a number array with difference between sum of each array is minimal

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm, partitioning

I am trying to create a function in JS/TS that returns N number of arrays with same length using all the elements in a number array A, with minimal difference in sum of elements in new arrays.
The size of number array A will be always divisible by N. This means we can always create N arrays with equal length.
All I found was this resource which not exactly what I am looking for

**Reference:** https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-array-into-two-subarrays-such-that-difference-of-their-sum-is-minimum/?tab=article but this is just to calculate the difference.

I have tried partion method which gives us N number of arrays with sum of each array is equal but the number of elements in arrays will be different.

```
function createGroups(baseArray:number[], numberOfGroupsNeeded:number){
 // sumOfBaseArray/numberOfGroupsNeeded = average sum of splitted arrays
 // return splited arrays with the same length
 //      and the difference in the sum of each array are minimal
}
```

**Example Input:** `baseArray:number[] = [5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1]` , `numberOfGroupsNeeded = 2`

`let sumOfBaseArray:number = baseArray.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0)`

`let requiredSumForEachNewArrays = sumOfBaseArray/numberOfGroupsNeeded;`

Sum of resulted arrys should be closer to `requiredSumForEachNewArrays`  which is **8.5 ≈ 9**

```
    Output: [4, 3, 2] & [5, 2, 1]
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Please add an example (input, expected output), your code and debug-information (and failing output (if exists))

Comment: @MrSmith42 thanks for your reply. Edited the question with inputs. I dont have an error output. Infact I dont have a working example yet. thanks

Comment: If you have N arrays, what does it mean for the "difference" in their sums to be minimal?  There are ½(N²-N) pairs of arrays.  Are you saying that you want to minimize the *largest* of those?  Or is there some least-squares sense of minimizing that you're doing?  Without this information I don't think the question is specified enough to be answered.

Comment: @jcalz Hi, thanks for your reply. I have added more info about the expected output, Hope I am clear now.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it does not.  If you split into only two groups, then there is only one difference to minimize.  But if you have N groups, then you have ½(N²-N) differences, and you can't just say "minimize them" without explaining what you mean.  For example, with four groups which sum to a, b, c, and d, you have six differences |b-a|, |c-a|, |d-a|, |c-b|, |d-b|, and |d-c|.  You can't always minimize all of them; minimizing some of them might necessarily increase others, so you have to explicitly say in what sense they should be minimized.

Comment: Note that you are trying to solve a [balanced number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_number_partitioning#Balanced_partitioning_with_larger_cardinalities) problem, and in general it looks like this is NP-hard no matter which criterion you choose for optimization.  What is your use case?

Comment: @jcalz I have a pool of users, each user have a rank and I am trying to create N number of groups based on users rank. And in the end each group should have a balanced total rank so that one is not significantly stronger than the other. The number of users and number of groups required should be passed as arguments too.